# Why would one use an automatically shrinking thread pool?

Tags: performance, concurrency, language-agnostic

I find the dynamic shrinking functionality generally obsolete, all reasons I can think of (stack size of 1 MB, or additional file descriptor, tiny additional OS scheduling overhead) do not seem to counterweight the latency overhead of firing up a new thread lazily.

What would be the best use case for an automatically shrinking (timeout-based) thread pool (Posix threads on x86_64 hardware) to demonstrate it is still a usable pattern?

Comment: A pool without a retirement policy is a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Shrinking a thread pool will free up resources (mostly RAM) that will then become available for other processes running on the same computer or perhaps on a different VM running on the same hardware. The RAM can also be used to speed things up via caching.

See also:

- [Thread vs ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230003/thread-vs-threadpool)
- [When to use thread pool in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145304/when-to-use-thread-pool-in-c)
- [Thread Pool vs Thread Spawning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049948/thread-pool-vs-thread-spawning)

In general the consensus seems to be that if it's a short lived task a thread pool will offer performance benefits. For longer lived threads it will be less significant.

Comment: Can you please elaborate re: what RAM (apart from 1MB of stack) and clarify what you mean by leaking stack memory (I don't think it is possible in principle).

Comment: Threads can be large, having fewer of them consumes less memory. You are right about the stack, it's hard to leak that :)

Comment: RAM footprint of a thread parked in a pool is just 1 MB of stack, nothing else.